# How to make the div content(it may be input, radio, check box, numeric slider, drop down etc) readonly and enable when click on button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with content. It should be readonly by default and when I click on button I should be able to edit the page.

Note: It should be read only mode by default and should not even allow to edit using any keyboard actions,mouse actions and touch actions.

Comment: add code please.

Comment: you should add what you have tried ,

Comment: The content of a div is read-only by default. What is your actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) attribute to achieve it

**HTML :**

```
<div contenteditable="false" id="makeItEdit">This is a paragraph. It is editable. 
Try to change this text.</div>
```

**Jquery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#makeItEdit").on('click',function(event){

      $(this).attr('contenteditable',true);
   })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make Div read only what you can do is you have to create a text area and make that read only like this

```
$("input, textarea").prop("readonly", true);  



<div>
  <input type="text" value="value" />  <br />
  <textarea>value</textarea>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contentEditable` attribute, more details from mdn https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable

```js
function toggle() {
    var div = document.getElementById('content');
    if (div.contentEditable === 'inherit') {
        div.contentEditable = true;
    } else {
        if (div.contentEditable === true) {
            div.contentEditable = false;
        } else {
            div.contentEditable = true;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    Some content
</div>
<button onclick="toggle()">TOGGLE</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my slice of cake for you:

---

```js
$('#edit_content').click(() => {
    let content = $('div')
    let isEditable= content.is('.editable');
    content.prop('contenteditable',!isEditable).toggleClass('editable');
    console.log(isEditable);
});
```

```css
.content {
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.editable {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
<br>
<button id="edit_content">Edit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this one?. I think you make the div editable on click.
by using "HTML DOM contentEditable Property"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <div id="myP">This is a paragraph. Click the button to make me editable.</div>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myP").contentEditable = true;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The p element above is now editable. Try to change its text.";
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```